# Implications of convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

I would like to ask you for an help to show $(\star)$

Consider a sequence of real-valued random variables $\{X_n\}_n$ and assume $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)\rightarrow_d (N,\sigma^2)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, with $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sigma^2<\infty$

Could you help me to show that

$$
Pr(\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)<\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{n}(\mu-\frac{1}{2}))=\Phi(\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{n}(\mu-\frac{1}{2})}{\sigma}) +o(1)  \hspace{ 3 cm} (\star)
$$

where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal cdf?

I know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Pr(\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)<c)=\Phi(\frac{c}{\sigma}) $ for any constant $c$ but I don't know how to deal with a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: Both $Pr(\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)<\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{n}(\mu-\frac{1}{2}))$ and $\Phi(\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{n}(\mu-\frac{1}{2})}{\sigma})$ tend to $u(\frac 1 2-\mu)$, where $u$ is a step function with $u(0)=\frac 1 2$, so their difference is $o(1)$.

Comment: Note that $\frac 1 2$ in $\Phi$ should not be divided by $sigma$.

Comment: Thanks, are you using to the asymptotic normality assumption?

Comment: It only uses the fact that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)$ converges to a distribution with $F(0-)=\frac 1 2$ because $\sqrt n(\mu-\frac 1 2)$ either is $0$ or drifts away to one of the infinities.